# Syntax of --glue option for Java Cucumber cli (cucumber.api.cli.Main)

Tags: java, eclipse, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit

I'm trying to run Cucumber cli from a Windows command line (Windows 10). All good thus far. I can get it to load my *.feature files from the correct place and tell me which methods I need to implement. I've created a class with @Give, @When, @Then notation on the class methods and then compiled my class cleanly.

The .class file sits in a com\company\automation\ subdirectory of the \bin directory of my Eclipse Project and all the supporting jars sit in C:\java. I use the following syntax in a .bat file to try to run but Cucumber reports it can't find my methods and prompts me to write these "missing steps".

The command I'm using is:

java -classpath "C:\java\*";"C:\Users\Mark\workspace\Company Automation\bin\*" cucumber.api.cli.Main --glue "C:\Users\Mark\workspace\Company Automation\bin\com\company\automation" "C:\Users\Mark\workspace\Company Automation\Features"

My implementation of the "missing steps" is below:

```
package com.company.automation;

import cucumber.api.PendingException;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;

public class CucumberImplementation {

    @Given("^I am a visitor$")
    public void i_am_a_visitor() throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        throw new PendingException();
    }

    @When("^I visit \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void i_visit(String arg1) throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        throw new PendingException();
    }

    @Then("^there must be a \"([^\"]*)\" element$")
    public void there_must_be_a_element(String arg1) throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        throw new PendingException();
    }

    @Then("^the \"([^\"]*)\" element must contain a \"([^\"]*)\" element$")
    public void the_element_must_contain_a_element(String arg1, String arg2) throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        throw new PendingException();
    }

    @Then("^the \"([^\"]*)\" element must contain a \"([^\"]*)\" link$")
    public void the_element_must_contain_a_link(String arg1, String arg2) throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        throw new PendingException();
    }

    @Then("^there must be a \"([^\"]*)\" element after the \"([^\"]*)\" element$")
    public void there_must_be_a_element_after_the_element(String arg1, String arg2) throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        throw new PendingException();
    }

}
```

I've tried all kinds of different path forms for the --glue option including classpath:com.company.automation, classpath:com.company.automation.CucumberImplementation.class and similar but with backslashes and forwardslashes. It appears that whatever syntax I use for the argument to the --glue option, Cucumber seems to ignore it completely and not even throw a PendingException on the first step. Nor does it complain that the argument to the --glue option is an invalid path if I just put gibberish there.

Using cucumber-core-1.2.4.jar as the base.

Comment: have you tried something like `--glue com.myco.myproject.cucumber.steps`? Just reference the package containing your steps.

Comment: Tried that.. --glue com.company.automation I've tried just about every format I can think of now..

Comment: @MarkWilkinson, did you eventually have success with this?  I'm struggling with the same issue.

Comment: Were you able to get it working? I am facing the same issue.. pls help

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem.

This is how I solved it (thanks to comments above):

```
--glue com.test.app
```

where "com.test.app" is a package of my step definition file.